# Moq False Positives : MoqException is being caught by program try/catch logic

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm writing unit tests for some legacy code and have come across a situation where I'm getting false positives for my unit tests. A simplified example is below.

If I forget to set up an implementation for DoSomething, I would want the test below to fail with a MockException. However, the exception is actually caught by the try/catch in the business logic, and so the test appears to pass. VerifyAll likewise does not cause a failure as the method has been 'called'.

I found a [request for change](http://moq.uservoice.com/forums/11304-general/suggestions/4956257-add-a-new-strict-mockbehavior-that-does-not-throw) related to this issue, but there doesn't seem to be a response to it.

Any ideas on how I can ensure this test works?

```
public class SUT 
{
    public ISystem iSystem { get; set; } // complicated web service

    public void Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            iSystem .DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Report error
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDoSomething()
    {
        var mr = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var iSystem = mr.Create<ISystem>();
        var foo = new Foo { Interface = interface.Object };

        foo.DoSomething();

        mr.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unit tests should isolate the tested class, SUT is behaving correctly by logging (and swallowing) the error - if you wanted to test the throw, that belongs in an iSystem test. You could have the test still fail by detecting the unexpected error logging call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is not really related to moq, or to testing, but more of a design / exception handling practice.

I would imagine that the constructor of `Foo` is not the proper place to handle all unexpected errors.

You probably want to have unexpected exceptions such as `OutOfMemoryException`, `StackOverflowException` and other unexpected exception to bubble up to a centralized place where all fatal errors will be handled.

Typically, that would be:

- For WPF : the AppDomain.UnhandledException event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)
- For CommandLine applications: UnhandledExceptionEventHandler (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)
- For ASP.Net, the Application_Error method in global.asax (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.140).aspx)

Bottom line is. In order to solve your case, first, write a brand new test where you set-up your `DoSomething()` method to throw an exception

Use

```
mr.Setup(o => o.DoSomething().Throws<MyUnexpectedException>();
```

Then, assert that instantiating `Foo` does not swallow `MyUnexpectedException` and is actually thrown.

By doing so, you will be forced to change your `catch` statement and use more specific types (it is a very bad practice to use `Exception` in a catch block)

Then, by changing your architecture, `MockException`, which inherits from `Exception` will not be handled by your `catch` block.